# How many planes can be drawn in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given that they 're not parallel to the coordinate axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Consider the following geometric figure: [image]

I have eight vertices and I want to know how many planes I can define using those eight vertices. However, the planes must not be parallel to the planes $xOy$, $yOz$ or $xOz$.

Since I need three vertices to define a plane, I can choose 3 out of any of the 8 and then subtract the planes which are parallel to the coordinate axis -- that is, the faces of the cube.

> $\begin{pmatrix}8\\ 3\end{pmatrix}-6=50$

Is this correct?

Comment: By defining a plane using three points you pick each of the faces of the cube more than once. Also there are other planes you pick more than once. So you have a good idea, but you have to avoid double-counting.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us *correctly* count the total of possible planes.

There are $6$ square faces and $6$ "diagonal rectangles" that define a plane by *four* of the vertices. Hence from the ${8\choose 3}$ total point triplets, we have to subtract $(6+6)\cdot 3({4\choose 3}-1)$ triplets to find the total number of planes defined. Only then subtract the $6$ forbidden planes.

Comment: Subtract $(6+6)\cdot 3({4\choose 3}-1)$ from ${8\choose 3}$? It ends up in a negative number...

Comment: Just subtract $(6+6)(4-1) = 36$ instead.  The answer is $56 - 36 = 20$, which are the $6$ faces, the $6$ diagonal rectangles, and $8$ more which are the faces of the the two tetrahedra, each formed by $4$ opposite corners.